# Converting or exporting audio files

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, file-format

I am looking for a way to convert or export an audio file that would be either in MP3 or M4A format, to any of the following file formats: WMA, MP3, AIF, or OGG. I am aware of PCM, which is a CAF File, but Unity does not support this file. I cannot use AFConvert or anything similar with the iOS SDK in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use CoreAudio. Especially the ExtFileReader C API. Apple has sample codes for an offline conversion example on how to use this. (Can't post the link, because it is behind authentication.)

Answer (score 0):

Here try this link if you haven't:-
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Listings/ExtAudioFileConvert_cpp.html

It has a C++ class to perform audio conversion. A good look at the project will help you in understanding the concepts to some extent.
you can also refer to this PDF:
http://izotope.fileburst.com/guides/iZotope_iOS_Audio_Programming_Guide.pdf

The rough idea is that you need to understand the basics of each file format and set the various audio properties to save PCM or LPCM in to a specific format. For mp3 you do not get an encoder from apple but only a decoder as per my knowledge. But AAC or WAV formats can b used easily for the same purpose. for MP3 Lame encoder and decoder can be used but im not sure how to use it.

I hope it will help you achieve what u want.